# SSL Handshake Exception: Fatal Alert Handshake Failure

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, retrofit2, sslhandshakeexception

I'm attempting to perform the following `curl` command using Java and Retrofit.

`curl -k -d "grant_type=client_cert" -H "Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedValue" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --cert ./certificate.pem https://taget-domain.com`

At this point, when using Java code (see below) I receive the error:

`HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

**Full trace posted [here](https://pastebin.com/KM6KgJ3B).**

The code loads the local key store, constructs a trust manager factory, and sets the SSL context using the trust manager factory. The Retrofit configuration then retrieves the X509 trust manager and sets the HTTP client to use the SSL context socket factory and X509 trust manager.

Does anyone know what is or could be the issue and corresponding solution?

Below are the two pertinent Java code snippets:

**Certificate Configuration**

```
public KeyStore keyStore(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance(getType());

        Certificate certificate;

        try (InputStream in = applicationContext.getResource(getCertificateResource())
                .getInputStream()) {

            certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(in);
        }

        // Configure key store.
        String cacertsPath = System.getProperty("cacerts");
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        Path keyStorePath = Paths.get(cacertsPath);
        keyStore.load(Files.newInputStream(keyStorePath), getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray());
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("certificateAlias", certificate);

        return keyStore;
}

public TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory(@Qualifier("keyStore") KeyStore keyStore)
            throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        // Configure trust manager factory.
        String trustManagerFactoryAlgo = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(trustManagerFactoryAlgo);
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        return trustManagerFactory;
}

public SSLContext sslContext(
            @Qualifier("trustManagerFactory") TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

        X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0];

        // Configure SSL context.
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(getProtocol());
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null);

        return sslContext;
}
```

**Retrofit Configuration**

```
public OkHttpClient authOkHttpClient(@Qualifier("sslContext") SSLContext sslContext, @Qualifier("trustManagerFactory")
      TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory) {

    // Configure OkHttp3 logging.
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(Level.BODY);

    // Configure HTTP client.
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers()[0];
    httpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), x509TrustManager);

    return httpClientBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Run with **-Djavax.net.debug=all** and come back with the full trace

Comment: @EugèneAdell: added trace as suggested.

Comment: The server is sending a Certificate Request, and your client doesn't send any certificate, this is the reason of the failure.

Comment: For `curl` you specified `--cert ./certificate.pem` and if that file actually contains a cert _and private key_ (but is imprecisely named) then `curl` sent that cert and used it to authenticate. To do the same in Java, put that cert+key in some available keystore, and pass the result of a `KeyManagerFactory` on that keystore to the _first_ argument to `SSLContext.init` much as you now use `TrustManagerFactory` in the second argument.